# How to add _.debounce to Foundation range slider?

Tags: jquery, underscore.js, zurb-foundation

I have a Foundation range slider on my site. The intended function is that when the slider is moved, it submits an Ajax query and updates a list of search results. This is my JQuery for when the slider changes:

```
$('[data-slider]').on('change.fndtn.slider', function(){
    $('#location-ajax-filter').trigger('change');
});
```

This works perfectly. However, I've noticed that it fires a zillion times. On page size change, on page load, on slight movement of the slider, etc. This is something I would like to have better control over. It seems to me that the Foundation range slider is lacking one fundamental thing - a stop event like the JQueryUI slider has. I don't want the overhead of JQueryUI, so I don't want to use it.

Since I already have _underscore.js as part of my build, I figured why not use the _.debounce to control the firing. The thing I need help with is how to rewrite the code above.

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work - I think I'm calling the debounce function in the wrong place?

```
$('[data-slider]').on('change.fndtn.slider', function(){
    _.debounce($('#location-ajax-filter').trigger('change'), 3000);
});
```

Also, is there a way I can extend this to address page size changes and keep it from firing on page load?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE

I think I may have sorted out how to use the debounce function, however, I still have not resolved how to keep the data slider from firing on page load and page resize. This is how I partially resolved the issue:

```
$('[data-slider]').on('change.fndtn.slider', _.debounce(function(){
   $('#location-ajax-filter').trigger('change');
}, 1000));
```

Still need help if anyone knows the answer for the page load and size.